# ImportError: libpython3.6m.so.1.0 on Google App Engine

Tags: python, python-3.x, google-app-engine, docker

I use Google app engine with **Python Env + Flask + gunicorn + meinheld**

but when I deploy my app on

```
runtime_config:
  python_version: 3
```

gcloud shows me this error

> ImportError: libpython3.6m.so.1.0: cannot open shared object file

*When importing **meinheld** causes the problem*

but when I deploy my app on

```
runtime_config:
  python_version: 3.5
```

Everything is fine... but I don't want to run with version 3.5

I try run with Dockerfile like this *(obviously with **runtime: custom** in app.yaml)*

```
FROM gcr.io/google-appengine/python
LABEL python_version=python3.6
RUN virtualenv --no-download /env -p python3.6

# Set virtualenv environment variables. This is equivalent to running
# source /env/bin/activate
ENV VIRTUAL_ENV /env
ENV PATH /env/bin:$PATH
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install python3.6-dev
ADD requirements.txt /app/
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
ADD . /app/
CMD exec gunicorn main:app -c gunicorn.conf.py -b :$PORT
```

but i cant run apt-get install python3.6-dev to install shared libs...

any ideas?

Comment: Hello, Google dev here. Can you clarify what you mean by "can't run apt-get install python3.6-dev"? What goes wrong at that step?